# What's wrong with nested tikzpicture and xelatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, nesting

I want to draw a line between to nested tikzpicture,while the code runs without any problem with `pdflatex`, the result of `xelatex` is not acceptable. I've to use `xelatex` because my document contains some RTL text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

    \node (container1) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [draw,] (child1) {Node 1's Child};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \node [right= 6cm of container1] (container2) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [draw,] (child2) {Node 2's Child};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \draw [<->] (child1) to [out=0,in=180] (child2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While I've to get the following picture 
[image]
the `xelatex` gives me the next one!
[image]

I don't know what's wrong with this engine, is a xelatex bug?

The main problem is raised by the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{xebaposter}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, ]

\tikzstyle{box} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node distance=7em, text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2.5em]


\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
    {
    eyecatcher=false,
    background=none,
    borderColor=black,
    textborder=faded,
    boxColorOne=yellow,
    headerColorOne=white,
    headerborder=closed,
    headershape=rounded,
    headershade=plain,
    }
    {}
    {title}
    {subtitle}
    {}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=base]{Common}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [box] (math) {math};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=kernel, column=1,]{Core}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [box] (stat) {statistics};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
      \draw [->,thick,red] (math) to [out=0,in=180] (stat);  
    \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

As I said above, there is no problem with `pdflatex` but the output with `xelatex` is not correct!.

`pdflatex` output:
[image]
`xelatex` output:
[image]
*`xebaposter` is a modified version of `baposter` that can handle RTL text with the aim of `xepersian` package.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` environments is not recommended, regardless which TeX engine you apply here. It can work within `pdflatex`, but rather by chance...

Answer (score 7):

You should avoid nested tikzpictures. There are several ways to do what you want, which I assume is to include one or more nodes in a container of some sort. One is by using `scope` instead of nodes. In the example below I have added one more node in `container1` and drawn a red dashed line around it, just to see what happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=container1]
    \node [draw,] (child1) {Node 1's Child};
    \node[below=1cm of child1]{Test};
    \draw[dashed,red!40](container1.south west) rectangle (container1.north east);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=container2,shift={($(container1.east)+(6cm,0)$)}]
    \node [draw,anchor=west] (child2) {Node 2's Child};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [<->] (child1) to [out=0,in=180] (child2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to use `fit` which is used to draw a node around a couple of other nodes. This is closer to what is done in the question since it encloses nodes with a node, but it is done the other order, first the enclosed nodes and then the enclosing. The same picture as above becomes (if you want a tighter fit just add `inner sep=0pt`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw,] (child1) {Node 1's Child};
  \node [below=1cm of child1](Test){Test};
  \node [draw=red!40,dashed,fit={(child1) (Test)}] (container1){};
  \node [draw,anchor=west,right=6cm of container1] (child2) {Node 2's Child};
  \draw [<->] (child1) to [out=0,in=180] (child2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A third alternative is to do two stand alone `tikzpicture`s using the option `remember picture` that means all names are remebered. Then use a third `tikzpicture` with an additional parameter `overlay`, meaning it does not take any space, that draws the arrow. (I have added `\usepackage{lipsum}` to the preamble to write some text between the pictures. Compile twice to get the arrow correct.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [draw,] (child1) {Node 1's Child};
  \node [below=1cm of child1](Test){Test};
  \draw[dashed,red!40](current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [draw,anchor=west] (child2) {Node 2's Child};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [<->,thick,red] (child1) to [out=0,in=180] (child2);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, Thanks for your reply. Actually, I want to make two objects in two different blocks of tikzposter, then draw a path between them. 
Your solution does not work in this case.

Comment: @javadr If you mean as two separate pictures with a line between I have added a third alternative.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work in my case. As I said there is no problem with pdflatex but there is some weird result with xelatex. I put the original problem in the question.